# Position absolute for parent ul stops anchor links working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, anchor, absolute

I've extended an existing old SpryMenuBar to include a dropdown menu. Whilst this works in Firefox and Chrome, in IE the anchor links in the submenu are not clickable and the pointer does not change on hover. The submenu ul-tag has position set to absolute, if I unset that then the anchor links show in IE11.

The SpryMenuBar does include event listeners for mouseover etc but surely this is just a css issue? How can I make the anchor links work with their parent ul position set to absolute? Any ideas (other than replace with a newer menu) please?

Html with hover classes added:

```
<ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal MenuBarActive">
          <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu MenuBarItemSubmenuHover" href="">INFO</a>
              <ul class="submenu MenuBarItemSubmenuHover">
                <li><a class="MenuBarItemHover" href="page1.php">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
 </ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* The outermost container of the Menu Bar, an auto width box with no margin or padding */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:normal;
    cursor: default;
    width: auto;
}
/* Set the active Menu Bar with this class, currently setting z-index to accomodate IE rendering bug: http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html */
ul.MenuBarActive
{
    z-index: 1000;
}
/* Menu item containers, position children relative to this container and are a fixed width */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 8.5em;
    float: left;
    background-color: #006930;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
}
/* Submenus should appear below their parent (top: 0) with a higher z-index, but they are initially off the left side of the screen (-1000em) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    z-index: 1020;
    cursor: default;
    /*width: 8.2em;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000em;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to auto so it comes onto the screen below its parent menu item */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
    margin-top:18px;    
    border-color:#006930;
    z-index:100;
}
/* Menu item containers are same fixed width as parent */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
    width: 15em;
    text-align:left;
}
/* Submenus should appear slightly overlapping to the right (95%) and up (-5%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}
/* Submenu that is showing with class designation MenuBarSubmenuVisible, we set left to 0 so it comes onto the screen */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    left: auto;
    top: 0;
}

/* Submenu containers have borders on all sides */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
/* Menu items are a light gray block with padding and no text decoration */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* background-color:#006930;*/
    padding: 0.3em 0.5em;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.submenu
{
    background-color:#006930;
}
/* Menu items that have mouse over or focus have a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    color:#006930;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus are set to MenuBarItemHover with a blue background and white text */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
    background-color:#FFF;
    color: #006930;
}

/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
/* Menu items that have a submenu have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenu and are set to use a background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRight.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}
/* Menu items that are open with submenus have the class designation MenuBarItemSubmenuHover and are set to use a "hover" background image positioned on the far left (95%) and centered vertically (50%) */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
    background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 95% 50%;
}

/* HACK FOR IE: to make sure the sub menus show above form controls, we underlay each submenu with an iframe */
ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1010;
}
/* HACK FOR IE: to stabilize appearance of menu items; the slash in float is to keep IE 5.0 from parsing */
@media screen, projection
{
    ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
    {
        display: inline;
        f\loat: left;
        background: #FFF;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Ah! If I remove the background colour from the submenu ul and li css then it exposes the word 'false'! Presumably generated somewhere in the js.

UPDATE2: Think I might have solved it! The following js is creating an iframe in IE:

```
    if(typeof document.uniqueID != "undefined")
    {
        this.createIframeLayer(menu);
    }

// createIframeLayer for Menu Bar
// creates an IFRAME underneath a menu so that it will show above form controls and ActiveX
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.createIframeLayer = function(menu)
{
    var layer = document.createElement('iframe');
    layer.tabIndex = '-1';
    layer.src = 'javascript:false;';
    menu.parentNode.appendChild(layer);
    
    layer.style.left = menu.offsetLeft + 'px';
    layer.style.top = menu.offsetTop + 'px';
    layer.style.width = menu.offsetWidth + 'px';
    layer.style.height = menu.offsetHeight + 'px';
};
```

Comment: In the last update in your original post, it looks like you have found the cause of the issue. Here, I want to confirm with you whether your issue is resolved or not? I try to test your code on my side but it is not creating the dropdown menu and due to that reason I am not able to produce the issue. If your issue persists then please try to provide a proper code that we can try to run with the IE browser to check for the issue. In the past, I have seen similar issues caused by CSS z-index. You can also try to check it.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT yes I have solved it thank you. Yes I tested z-index first. Not sure if I can delete this post or whether I need to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript for SpryMenuBar, originally created by Dreamweaver I believe, was creating an iframe which was interfering with the menu behaviour in the IE browser. Once removed it worked ok. A note in the code says the iframe is "so that it will show above form controls and ActiveX"; we haven't any form controls so will risk removing it.

My work-around solution of commenting out the line calling function `createIframeLayer` is below:

```
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.showSubmenu = function(menu)
{
    if(this.currMenu)
    {
        this.clearMenus(this.currMenu);
        this.currMenu = null;
    }

    if(menu)
    {
        this.addClassName(menu, "MenuBarSubmenuVisible");
        if(typeof document.all != 'undefined' && typeof window.opera == 'undefined' && navigator.vendor != 'KDE')
        {
            if(!this.hasClassName(this.element, "MenuBarHorizontal") || menu.parentNode.parentNode != this.element)
            {
                menu.style.top = menu.parentNode.offsetTop + 'px';
            }
        }
        if(typeof document.uniqueID != "undefined")
        {
            // iframe was outputting 'false' in IE11 stopping links from working
            //this.createIframeLayer(menu);
        }
    }
    this.addClassName(this.element, "MenuBarActive");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.